# Running a Python Application at Startup

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to write a custom login program for a linux system using Python 3. what is the best way to have an application automatically run at startup?

Comment: login to what? login to a shell, to gnome, ...

Comment: Most linux distros have a "run at startup" in the system preferences. Just add your python script to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either a System V Init script, or one of the more modern solutions like upstart.

The [Linux Standard Base describes qualities of the init scripts in detail](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html).

It's usually easiest to start with one of the existing scripts in `/etc/init.d` and adapt it to match your use case.

You may also choose to overload/override a particular runlevel's behavior.  For that you should look in more detail at `/etc/inittab` and [`inittab(5)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab%205).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reference. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If it is the login program for X11, you can put it into ~/.xinitrc. It is X session startup script.